# Use Geolocation and Geocoding at the same time - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I try using `Geolocation` and `Geocoding` on a homepage. So when page is loaded the location of the user should be display in on a map. So I found this code to get the current location of the user:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
            function showlocation() {
               // One-shot position request.
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
            }

      function callback(position) {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

             document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
         document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;

        var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLong
                });      

                marker.setMap(map);
        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
      function initMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          zoom: 1,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

      }
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

This works fine. But I now want to add a textbox that the user can change the address (for example if it's not correct or an error occured). I found `Geocoding` and I found this article:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Now the `Geolocation` doesn't work anymore. So I searched a solution to work with them both. And this is my question right now:

How can I use `Geolocation` and `Geocode` at the same time?

Hope someone can help me

Comment: may what is you question ,do you wan to display the address...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I want to display the location in a map. So `Geolocation` should get the current location and show it on a map and if it's wrong or an error occured the user can type the address manually in a textbox.

Comment: But we can get the current location of the user ,but i don't know how to edit the address..

Comment: But i think by using setContent() in the infowindow we can set i think

Comment: What do you mean with `setContent()`? I am new to JavaScript and really new to `Geolocation`

Comment: "setContent()" where you can write you message that can be put in the info window..

Comment: Okay, but is this relevant to type address into textbox for displaying it on a map?

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                        infowindow.setContent(html);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker, html);
                        // infowindow.setContent(html);
                        // infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
```

Comment: Now, the Geolocation doesn't work anymore. But thanks for help :)

Comment: I found this article, in which the whole code is explained, and I understand the code now much better :) http://www.torbenleuschner.de/blog/628/html5-geolocation-api-standort-in-google-maps-anzeigen/